# Adding a list of spotify uri's to a spotify playlist

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

Hi I am trying to add a list of songs to spotify, the list is contained in tracksUri which after calling SPTTrack.trackswithURIs is expected to return an array of tracks, which can then be added to spotify with the SPTPlaylistSnapshot addTracksToPlaylist method.  Where am I going wrong?

```
SPTTrack.tracksWithURIs(tracksUri as [AnyObject], session: session, callback: {
        (error, objects) in
        if (error == nil) {
            let myArray:NSArray = objects as AnyObject! as! NSArray
            list.addTracksToPlaylist(myArray as [AnyObject], withSession: session, callback: {
                (error) in
                if (error == nil) {
                    self.saveSongs()
                }
            })

        }
    })
```